# jquery doesn't work with string variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

is this a bug or expected? (google Chrome Screenshot)

When I use the hard-coded String, it works, but when I use the same string in a variable, it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: show us actual code ....see  [mcve]

Comment: and please don't posts screenshots of code/errors/... unless they only are graphically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable contains a string with two backslashes in it, but when you type out the string yourself, you're typing a string with only one backslash in it. (Typing `\\` in a quoted string results in one `\`, since the backslash is an escape character.)